# Modify a string in a .properties file with batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd, insert

I am trying to modify a certain property in my csm.properties by executing a script. 
I looked up a lot and in the end, came to this code.

```
set "search=CLASSPATH"
set "insert=CLASSPATH^=plugins^/Numbering.jar^\^:"

set "textFile="%workingPlace%bin\csm.properties""

FOR /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%textFile%" ^& break ^> "%textFile%" ') do (
    FOR /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%g IN ("%%i") DO (
        IF /i "%%g" == %search% (
            set "line=%%i"
                setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
                >>"%textFile%" echo(!line:%search%=%insert%!
                endlocal
        )ELSE (
        %%i
        )
    )
)
```

This code should read every line in my file and use `=` as a delimiter. If the code gets "CLASSPATH" as property, that line should get modified.
But it seems like CLASSPATH isn't found.

This is how csm.properties looks like:

```
#Tue Jul 10 08:50:23 CEST 2018
JAVA_ARGS=-Xmx20000M -DLOCALCONFIG\=true -splash\:data/splash.png -Dmd.class.path\=$java.class.path -Dcom.nomagic.osgi.config.dir\=configuration -Desi.system.config\=data/application.conf -Dlogback.configurationFile\=data/logback.xml -Dsun.locale.formatasdefault\=true -Dinitial.user.language\=de
JAVA_HOME=jre1.8.0_152
BOOT_CLASSPATH=lib/xalan.jar
MAIN_CLASS=com.nomagic.osgi.launcher.ProductionFrameworkLauncher
MAC_JAVA_ARGS="-Xdock\:name\=Cameo Systems Modeler" -Xdock\:icon\=bin/md.icns -Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar\=true
APP_ARGS=
DEFAULT_MEMORY_SETTINGS_64=-Xmx[30%,1200,4000]M
DEFAULT_MEMORY_SETTINGS_32=-Xmx800M
CLASSPATH=lib/patch.jar\:lib/brand_api.jar
CONSOLE=false
```

After modifications, `CLASSPATH`should look like this:

```
CLASSPATH=plugins/Numbering.jar\:lib/patch.jar\:lib/brand_api.jar
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am not allowed to use powershell. So pipelining the results to a new file and overriding the old file with the latest one, should do the work, I hope?

Comment: So, If I use my delims and tokens on the first loop, will the result be the same?

Comment: I can make batch work, but it will need to write to a new file, then delete old and rename the newfile.. same result you want.

Comment: I would love to see that solution of yours.

Comment: Also about my 2 for loops. I think, I need them because of line `) ELSE ( %%i )`. If I dont have those 2 loops `%%i` would just return the string before `=`

Comment: still do not need the second for loop

Comment: just cleaning up some comments in the meanwhile..

Comment: @GerhardBarnard Are you still there? :)

Comment: Sorry for the delay, had a major incident to attend to.. posting answer now.

Comment: @Compo Why should I post a question over again and again? I looked up the code from other stackoverflow questions and wrote my own code that way. Since I am a newby in batch scripts, there is no better way, than searching on stackoverflow

Comment: @Compo I took my sources from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25967146/batch-script-to-modify-properties-file and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23075953/batch-script-to-find-and-replace-a-string-in-text-file-without-creating-an-extra/23076141.

Comment: I didnt took that code, like I wrote in the comments, I wrote that code while referring to those 2 links from my previous comment

Comment: Show me where you took the line from in my initial comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183727/discussion-between-dnsiv-and-compo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simpler...

```
@echo OFF
setlocal

set "search=CLASSPATH"
set "insert=plugins/Numbering.jar\:"

set "textFile=%workingPlace%bin\csm.properties"

(FOR /f "usebackq tokens=1* delims==" %%i in ("%textFile%") do (
   if "%%i" equ "%search%" (
      echo %search%=%insert%%%j
   ) else if "%%j" neq "" (
      echo %%i=%%j
   ) else (
      echo %%i
   )
)) > temp.tmp

move /Y temp.tmp "%textFile%"
```

Comment: This might work this way, but I can't hardcode  `\:lib/patch.jar\:lib/brand_api.jar` as the classpath varies from user to user. I am writing this script for multiple people

Comment: Just fixed this point... So, you really are _not_ "replacing", but "inserting" a new value, isn't it?

Comment: Exactly. I am executing your code right now, but after execution the whole file is empty. So I guess there is still something wrong

Comment: Remove the `move` command and the `> temp.tmp` part and confirm that the output is correct...

Comment: My directory path cant be found. So the problem lies in the initialisation of my textFile variable. This `set "textFile=%workingPlace%bin\csm.properties" ` causes the problem with
`set workingPlace="C:\Program Files\Cameo Systems Modeler\"`

Comment: Do _not_ include quotes in the value. Enclose both the variable _and_ the value in quotes: `set "workingPlace=C:\Program Files\Cameo Systems Modeler\"`

Comment: ... like I did in my `set "textFile=%workingPlace%bin\csm.properties"` command...

Comment: Just include the quotes when they are needed! `command "%workingPlace%"`(like everybody does)...

Comment: Excuse me, but all these problems are _not_ related to your question nor to my answer... I suggest you to open a new question in order to get aid about this point...

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't want to deepen the question this way, but I am really really thankful to you. It works now and I also learned something new. I had some misconcepts in my head like `set x="x y"`, that I didnt know, that this is incorrect code. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

You can give this a go:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

 set "replace=plugins^/Numbering.jar^\^:"
 set "textFile=%workingPlace%bin\csm.properties""

  for /f %%i in ('type "%textFile%" ^& break ^> "%textFile%" ') do (
     set "line=%%i"
     for /f "tokens=1* delims==" %%a in ("%%i") do (
     if "%%a"=="CLASSPATH" (
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        >>"%textFile%" echo(!line!%replace%
        ) else (
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        >>"%textFile%" echo(!line!
        endlocal
     )
  )
)
```

Similar theory, it will only replace the full string if the first token (%%i) matches `CLASSMAP`

Please do not change the double quotations in the `set` commands.

Comment: Unfortunately I am getting a syntax error as output

Comment: And what is declared as `%%j` ?

Comment: Please copy and try again

Comment: %%j is the value after = for each line

Comment: Well.. it kinda worked, but now everything else from CLASSPATH has been removed. I just wanted to add a new string to CLASSPATH

Comment: Any line that contains more than one `=` got cut off

Comment: `for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" ` --> `for /f "tokens=1* delims==" `

Comment: But that is compeltely not replacing.. it is appending to a line

Comment: @lotpings. I know, I work with 2 tokens and prefer to show i am working with only 2.

Comment: But not at the cost of cutting off needed user content.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard that's right. Sorry maybe the code was misleading, since I took some part of another stakoverflow post.

Comment: @lotpings. Are there any needed user content here other than the 2 tokens?

Comment: You already accepted an answer, but ammended mine to suit the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution for this string replacement task using only internal commands of `cmd.exe` with exception of **FINDSTR**.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

if not defined workingPlace set "workingPlace=%~dp0"
set "TextFile=%workingPlace%bin\csm.properties"
if not exist "%TextFile%" goto EndBatch

set "TempFile=%TEMP%\csm.properties.tmp"
set "FoundInfo="

(for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /N "^" "%TextFile%"') do (
    set "Line=%%I"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "Line=!Line:*:=!"
    if not defined FoundInfo (
        if defined Line (
            if /I "!Line:~0,10!" == "CLASSPATH=" (
                if /I "!Line!" == "CLASSPATH=" (
                    echo !Line!plugins/Numbering.jar
                    endlocal
                    set "FoundInfo=1"
                ) else if "!Line:plugins/Numbering.jar=!" == "!Line!" (
                    set "Line=!Line:~0,10!plugins/Numbering.jar\:!Line:~10!"
                    echo !Line!
                    endlocal
                    set "FoundInfo=1"
                ) else (
                    endlocal
                    goto DeleteTempFile
                )
            ) else (
                echo(!Line!
                endlocal
            )
        ) else (
            echo/
            endlocal
        )
    ) else (
        echo(!Line!
        endlocal
    )
))>"%TempFile%"

if not defined FoundInfo echo CLASSPATH=plugins/Numbering.jar>>"%TempFile%"
move /Y "%TempFile%" "%TextFile%"

:DeleteTempFile
if exist "%TempFile%" del "%TempFile%"

:EndBatch
endlocal
```

Read my answer on [How to read and print contents of text file line by line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51579256/3074564) why command **FINDSTR** is used just to output every line in file `csm.properties` including empty lines ignored by **FOR** by default with line number and `:` to avoid that any line is ignored by **FOR**. The line number and the colon is removed by the command line `set "Line=!Line:*:=!"`.

There is the environment variable `FoundInfo` undefined at top of the batch file and which is set once a line starting case-insensitive with `CLASSSPATH=` is processed by the inner code of **FOR** loop. Every line in file after the line starting with `CLASSSPATH=` is just output without further processing including empty lines.

An empty line above line starting with `CLASSSPATH=` is also output with `echo/` without any further processing.

The first line starting case-insensitive with `CLASSPATH=` can be processed in three different ways:

1. The line contains just `CLASSPATH=`.
   In this case the line is output as `CLASSPATH=plugins/Numbering.jar` and that's it.
2. The line starts with `CLASSPATH=` and contains one or more characters, but not case-insensitive the string `plugins/Numbering.jar`.
   In this case the line is output within inserting `plugins/Numbering.jar\:` after `CLASSPATH=`.
   Please note that a line with just `CLASSPATH=` and one or more trailing spaces/tabs would result also in running into second branch resulting for example in output of `CLASSPATH=plugins/Numbering.jar\:`  with `\:` and the trailing whitespaces at end.
3. The line starts with `CLASSPATH=` and contains already case-insensitive the string `plugins/Numbering.jar` somewhere on the line.
   In this case the **FOR** loop is exited immediately with a jump to label `DeleteTempFile` without processing any further line from captured output of **FINDSTR**. So the last modification date of the file does not change because of nothing changed on file content. (I don't like a change last modification date on file content not really modified.)

After the **FOR** loop is checked if there was any line starting case-insensitive with `CLASSPATH=` at all in the file. The line `CLASSPATH=plugins/Numbering.jar` is appended to the temporary file if that was not the case.

Finally with temporary file definitely being different to `csm.properties`, the temporary file is moved over existing file `csm.properties` if that is possible at all and last the temporary file is deleted if it is still existing.

**Note 1:** The solution could be easier without usage of **FINDSTR** if file `csm.properties` contains no empty lines or it is acceptable that empty lines are removed during the update of line with `CLASSPATH=`.

**Note 2:** The line with `CLASSPATH=` at top of file `csm.properties` reduces the process time.

Summary of features of this solution:

1. Does not modify the text file on containing already `CLASSPATH=` with `plugins/Numbering.jar` somewhere on line.
2. Inserts `plugins/Numbering.jar\:` after `CLASSPATH=` only if there are other class paths (or trailing whitespaces) on this line.
3. Appends `plugins/Numbering.jar` to existing `CLASSPATH=` line not containing any other class path (and no trailing whitespaces on this line).
4. Appends entire `CLASSPATH=` line with `plugins/Numbering.jar` to file not containing this line at all if the file exists at least.
5. Keeps empty lines in text file and so modifies really only line with `CLASSPATH=` at beginning.
6. Does not modify lines with `VARIABLE==value` (value with equal sign at beginning) to `VARIABLE=value` (equal sign at beginning removed).
7. Does not modify spelling of `CLASSPATH=` and works for that reason also with `classpath=` or `ClassPath=` in file.
8. Does not remove lines starting with `;` being default of **FOR**'s end of line option (eol).

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `del /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `move /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

See also [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564) and [How to set environment variables with spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34402887/3074564) These answers explain why in most cases `set variable="value"` is not good and what is the difference to `set "variable=value"` which is the preferred syntax for definition of an environment variable with a string value.

See also [Symbol equivalent to NEQ, LSS, GTR, etc. in Windows batch files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47386323/3074564) explaining how string comparison works with command **IF** and why the operators `EQU` and `NEQ` designed primary for integer comparisons should be in general not used for comparing two strings although this is possible. The usage of `EQU` and `NEQ` for string comparisons can in some cases with not double quoted strings result in an unexpected comparison result.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal disabledelayedexpansion

set "search=CLASSPATH"
set "insert=plugins/Numbering.jar\:"

set "textFile=%workingPlace%bin\csm.properties"

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%i in ("%textFile%") do (
    for /f "tokens=1* delims==" %%g in ("%%i") do (
        if /i "%%g" == "%search%" (
            set "token1=%%g"
            set "token2=%%h"
            setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
            >> "%textFile%.tmp" echo(!search!=!insert!!token2!
            endlocal
        ) else (
            set "line=%%i"
            setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
            >> "%textFile%.tmp" echo(!line!
            endlocal
        )
    )
)

move "%textFile%" "%textFile%.bak" && move "%textFile%.tmp" "%textFile%"
```

Insert seems needed rather than a replace.

The for loop reads each line of `%textfile%` and the nested `for` loop
delimits on the `=` to store token 1 and token 2 with the remainder.

If `%search%` is found, then `!token1!` and `!token2!` is `set` the
token values. `set` usually can handle poison characters after
it so why it is used. Expansion is delayed so poison characters
are echoed to file without being expanded into the source.

If `%search%` is not found, the line is set to `!line!`,
expansion is delayed, and then the line is echoed to file.

Note:
`%workingPlace%` is unknown so correct the path as needed.