# Replace all using batch script

Tags: batch-file, escaping

I am trying to find "tenant_id = 1234" and replace to "tenant_id = 649" in a file with many occurrences. I found below code but unable to replace when I add =/space in variable. I tried escape character as well but some how its not working. Please let me know how to achieve this requirement using batch script in .bat file.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "INTEXTFILE=test.txt"
set "OUTTEXTFILE=test_out.txt"
set "SEARCHTEXT=tenant_id ^= 1234"
set "REPLACETEXT=tenant ^= 123456"

echo %SEARCHTEXT%

echo %REPLACETEXT%

for /f "delims=" %%A in ('type "%INTEXTFILE%"') do (
    set "string=%%A"
    set "modified=!string:%SEARCHTEXT%=%REPLACETEXT%!"
    echo !modified!>>"%OUTTEXTFILE%"
)

del "%INTEXTFILE%"
rename "%OUTTEXTFILE%" "%INTEXTFILE%"
endlocal
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Cant I use the code posted by me with some simple change to include =/space.

Comment: There is no easier way, see this on [DosTips.com](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1485)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows7+ contains PowerShell with the RegEx based `-replace` operator,
so you could use it directly or invoke it from batch as a tool.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "INTEXTFILE=test.txt"
set "SEARCHTEXT=tenant_id = 1234"
set "REPLACETEXT=tenant = 123456"

powershell -NoP -C "(Get-Content $ENV:INTEXTFILE) -Replace $ENV:SEARCHTEXT,$ENV:REPLACETEXT|Set-Content $ENV:INTEXTFILE"
```

In case the TEXTs contain characters `.*()^$[]`which would be interpreted as REs,
you can either switch to the `.Replace()` method (requires PSv3+)

```
powershell -NoP -C "(Get-Content $ENV:INTEXTFILE).Replace($ENV:SEARCHTEXT,$ENV:REPLACETEXT)|Set-Content $ENV:INTEXTFILE"
```

or automatically escape the TEXTs with [RegEx]::Escape()

```
powershell -NoP -C "(Get-Content $ENV:INTEXTFILE) -Replace [RegEx]::Escape($ENV:SEARCHTEXT),$ENV:REPLACETEXT|Set-Content $ENV:INTEXTFILE"
```

Comment: It is working fine.Thanks for helping to complete the task. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is an easy to achieve task with using [JREPL.BAT](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) written by **Dave Benham** which is a batch file / JScript hybrid to run a regular expression replace on a file using JScript.

```
@echo off
if not exist "test.txt" goto :EOF
if not exist "%~dp0jrepl.bat" goto :EOF

call "%~dp0jrepl.bat" "(tenant_id *= *)1234" "$1649" /F "test.txt" /O -
```

The batch file first checks if the file to modify exists at all and immediately exits if this condition is not true, see [Where does GOTO :EOF return to?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37518000/3074564)

The batch file **JREPL.BAT** must be stored in same directory as the batch file with the code above. For that reason the batch file checks next if **JREPL.BAT** really exists in directory of the batch file and exits if this condition is not true.

The meaning of the regular expression search string is:

- `(`...`)` ... Find a string referenced in replace string with `$1` to keep this part of found string unmodified starting with
- `tenant_id` ... case-sensitive string `tenant_id`
- `*` ... with 0 or more spaces
- `=` ... and an equal sign
- `*` ... and once more 0 or more spaces
- `1234` ... and the characters `1234`.

The replace string back-references the found string starting with `tenant_id` and ending before number `1234` with `$1` and replaces `1234` by `649`.

It would be also possible to use the regular expression `\d+` instead of `1234` in search string to find any number with one or more digits.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?` ... explains also `%~dp0` ... drive and path of argument 0 which is the batch file path always ending with a backslash.
- `echo /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `jrepl.bat /?`

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Cant I use the code posted by me with some simple change to include =/space.

Comment: @SaiKrishna Your "simple" code (my own is even easier, in real just one line) can't work for a file containing empty lines or lines containing one or more exclamation marks. A pure batch file solution using only Windows command processor commands with no help of other scripting languages including JScript supported since Windows 95 requires lots of additional code, see [Modify a string in a .properties file with batch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53322206/3074564) and [How to read and print contents of text file line by line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51579256/3074564).

Comment: @SaiKrishna Modifying a text file with pure `cmd.exe` commands is like using [Lineman's pliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lineman's_pliers) to drive nails into a hard board. A nail can be driven into a hard board also with Lineman's pliers more or less hardly depending on size and form of the nail (= string to modify) and the board (= file), but using a hammer (= other scripting language) makes this task much easier, more efficient and most likely also less painful.